# Copy existing png file and rename programmatically

Tags: java, android, bitmap, fileoutputstream

I have a png file in a folder "Movies" on the sdcard. I want to copy and rename that file in the same folder. I'm confused on how to properly call the method SaveImage.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        isbn = scanningResult.getContents();
        SaveImage();
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}


private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Movies/");
    String fname = "Image-"+ isbn +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question may not clear. Where do you want to copy that image to?

Comment: @TruongHieu In the same folder. I know I'm a noob. I simply want to duplicate the same file and rename it.

Comment: Is `isbn` a bitmap filename without extension, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is, how to properly call your `SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap)` method, right ? as your `SaveImage` method get a Bitmap as parameter you need to send it a Bitmap as parameter.

You can use [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to create a Bitmap object from your file and send this Bitmap object to your `SaveImage` method :

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/Movies/myimage.png");
SaveImage(bMap);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's nice to have answers to my stupid questions without being humiliated.

Comment: But you humiliate Rahul Sharma and TruongHieu. They give the only right answers to your question. You are completely wrong to convert a .png file to a bitmap and then save as a jpg under a different name. If you want to copy a file -like you asked- you should copy the file. Without using a bitmap. And converting .png to .jpg you did not mention either but accecpt is as the correct answer. Strange.

Answer (score 4):

**I simply want to duplicate the same file and rename it**

Thanks for making it more clearly. You can use this to copy from `source` file to `destination` file.

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Ok. So in the parameters "File src, File dst". How do i make those variables. eg. src = "/movies/file.png" dst = "/movies/file2.png". I'm trying to learn, but its alot of trail and error for me.

Comment: No. Your source and dest file are `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + /Movies/file.png` and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + /Movies/file2.png`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm sure you gave a correct answer, but the other one is all i needed. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @user2631279 Nevermind, it's good 'cos you solved your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Rename file:**

```
File source =new File("abc.png");
File destination =new File("abcdef.png");
source.renameTo(destination);
```

**Copy File:**

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Path source=Paths.get("abc.png");
Path destination=Paths.get("abcdef.png");
Files.copy(source, destination);
```